# Can we override the "Mark Complete" and the "Save" button on the Task detail page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button

can we override the **Mark Complete** and **Save** button with a lightning action button in the Task detail page? 
I checked the **Buttons, Links, and Actions** section in the Object Manager but these are not available.[image]

Also, can we add an error message against the **Mark Complete** buttons(Like OnClick action)?

Answer (score 0):

No Sam you cannot override the Mark complete and Save button directly.

The possibe workaround would be, creating the new lightning components (with implementation of **lightning:actionOverride** interface) for each **NewTask** and **StatusChange** buttons.

Thanks,